# Accessing a control from inside a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access a forms control from a class file in the App_Code directory but I keep getting the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Not really sure where I'm failing here but this is the code:

```
public static void openPage(Page page)
{
    DropDownList eventType = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("eventType");
    if (eventType.SelectedItem.Text == "Big Party")
    {
        DoSomeWork(); //should be changing values or visible options on the page
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it from my page like so:

```
Workflow.openPage(this);
```

It keeps telling my that the issue is from: `if (eventType.SelectedItem.Text == "Big Party")`
  Any ideas?

Comment: If you run debug in VSS and put eventType.SelectedItem.Text in the watch list what value is present in when the variable is displayed in the watch list?

Comment: If you would please show .aspx markup source of the page you are trying to find the control from I think this would be fairly easy to diagnose.

Comment: @Matthew - the page is over 2600 lines long (not code behind). I dont think I can, or would want to post that much. But I will see about cutting some of it out and posting just whats needed. @gsirianni - I'll try and see what I can do with that.

Comment: You should be able to simply create a new blank project and add just the code you are trying to do, then post that if the problem exists in your new project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is because FindControl is returning null, and you are trying to derefrence a null reference.  If you place a check for null before the code, it will stop throwing the exception.

```
if (eventType != null && eventType.SelectedItem.Text == "Big Party")
{
    DoSomeWork(); //should be changing values or visible options on the page    
}
```

Of course this won't give you want you're looking for.

Where are you calling Workflow.openPage from?  More than likely, you're calling it from too early in the page lifecycle and the control hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Right on the money. I actually figured this out based on gsirianni's comment. The control does have a value, but it's not populated at the time I'm calling this code. Gave you the answer because you gave more detail, though Joel's answer was correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like `page.FindControl()` is returning `null`.  That'd be the first place I'd look anyway.  Make sure you type your control name correctly, and that the control exists on the page at the point in the lifecycle when you call this method.

Comment: If that isn't the case, then it may be that no item is selected yet, in which case `SelectedItem` would be `null`

Comment: @Daniel yes it already has an item selected. @Joel the name is correct as far as I can tell from VS and when I view source.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a control called eventType on the page, but it is in a naming container, and your FindControl method is not locating it for that reason.

So eventType is null, so null.SelectedItem Throws a null reference exception.

If you are using a master page, and your are looking for a control on a child page then this is most certainly the case. What you will need to do is retrieve the appropriate control that implements INamingContainer, usually a ContentPlaceHolder

```
ContentPlaceHolder namingContainer = Page.PreviousPage.Controls(0).FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
```

And look in there for the control you are looking for.

```
DropDownList eventType = namingContainer.FindControl("eventType");
```

Here is an intro article on naming containers, and how to FindControls on pages that have more than one Naming container.

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2006/08/12/20546.aspx

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/05/14/using-findcontrol-and-previouspage-with-master-pages.aspx

Comment: It's just under the form tag.

Comment: This is not in a masterpage/content page either. Just a plain ol' form.

Comment: There are more controls that implement INamingContainer than ContentPlaceHolders.  But you can ensure that I am barking up the wrong tree.  Controls have a property called NamingContainer.  I would make sure that the naming container of "eventType" is in fact the page as you think it is.  This will have to be checked from its actual page of origin, and not in your App_Code class, as it is still returning null.

Comment: The 'eventType' name is just a fill in the blank. I broke down the code and posted soemthing that would make sense to people and not be domain specfic. The actual name is status. But I guess I can see how it may cause some confusion.